# Creating Static Links Using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am new to .htaccess

I have created many links which open up pages based on a search result.
The link addresses are, each link has a different `prid` such as 3110, 3111, 3222

```
http://mywebsite.com/prid-3110/1500-Sq-Ft-Residential-Plot-for-Sale-In-Arya-Shine-City-Irba-Ranchi-For-Rs-9.75-Lakh
```

I want this link to point to (ignore everything after the second slash)

```
 http://mywebsite.com/prid-3110/
```

My Current .htaccess rule is

```
RewriteRule ^prid-([0-9]+)$ views/propertyview.php?property_id=$1
```

The correct answer is working below

And add this the following  so everything else like CSS, Images work because your browser will know from where to start looking for files.

```
<head> <base href="../"> </head>
```

Comment: That dollar sign looks misplaced. You don't want your match to terminate on a digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^prid-(\d+)(?:/|$) views/propertyview.php?property_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

With `(?:/|$)` you avoid `prid-3110blabla`, but you can use only:

```
RewriteRule ^prid-(\d+) views/propertyview.php?property_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

without this test.

Comment: thank you please give some explanation so a newbee can understand what is going on thanks

Comment: Yes, you can read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression